# how do you turn off the vibration alert for incoming text messages on a samsung galaxy s3 mini?

Tags: sms, notifications, vibration, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I've gone through the settings menu but can only find options to change the vibration pattern, not to turn it off completely. Any ideas??

Answer (score 6):

On my Samsung Galaxy S3, this setting is inside the Text Messaging app, rather than as a general setting.

Open the Text Messaging app, and start the Settings menu.

About halfway down I have a block of Notification settings.
 
First being Notifications,
Second being Ringtone,
Third is Vibrate.
Uncheck and you're done.
Hope your Settings Menu is similar since its from the Samsung family.

Comment: I don't have any settings options in the text messaging app unfortunately!

Comment: You have to press the hard **menu** key, then pick **Settings** from the menu.

Comment: Answer is also good for Samsung Galaxy Ace 4 ([...] menu inside the Text Messaging app).